# How Can I put a php response into i javascript variable?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a .php document on my Server. This sents me a JSON string, if I call it in browser.
Now I want to put this reponse I get in browser into a JavaScript variable.
Does anyone know how to do this?

MFG Jochen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `XMLHttpRequest`, which enables to initiate HTTP requests from JavaScript code; don't pay attention to the misleading `XML` in the name.

All modern JavaScript libraries offer high-level functions to enhance the features of this function (e.g. `jQuery.ajax`).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  // 't' being the JS variable
   var t = <?php echo $json_string; ?>;
```

You may want to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) if you want the decoded string.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer!
But I want to take the Response I get from the php file into a JavaScript variable. in the php Response it isn´t one.

Comment: that's not what the op wanted to do. think he just want's to store the ajax response within the requesting js script

Comment: @Jochen: What do you mean by *Response*? Is it a PHP variable or a json string? Post your PHP code, so we could have a better understanding.

Comment: @kratenko: OP doesn't mention AJAX, so I am not gonna assume it, just because it mentions json string. Moreover, if its an AJAX response, it will be in a JS variable.

Comment: @jochen i admit i read it into the question. Maybe OP hasn't figured that part out, yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
var response = <?php echo $json_echo; ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

this way you can pass php variable to JS

```
<script> 
     var json_js = <?php echo $json_php; ?>; 
</script>
```